# Closing modal from controller in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem Question -

I have created a custom modal directive and now trying to close it from the controller but no succes so far. I am definitely doing something wrong in directive

//My Directive

```
angular.module('app').directive('modalDialog',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            show: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.hideModal = function() {
                scope.show = false;
            };
        },
        template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>" +
            "<div class='ng-modal-overlay'></div>" +
            "<div class='ng-modal-dialog'>"+
            "<div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div>"+
            "</div>"+
            "<button class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>Close</button>"+
            "</div>"
    }
});
```

// My controller

```
(function() {
    var myController = function($scope){

        $scope.newAdd = function(){
            if($scope.form.$valid){
                $scope.hideModal();//this is not working :( 
            }else{

            }
        }
    };
    myController .$inject = ['$scope'];
    angular.module('app').controller('myController ',myController );
}());
```

UPDATE 1

There is a form in my model as well. Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YUdxLUrpYevus8TY6rWB?p=preview)

When I click on Add button it should close the modal, if both the fields are present

Can anyone please help me ? Much appreciated

Comment: You're using an isolated scope, so on the parent you will never see the `hideModal` function you create in your directive.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup where you use the `modalDialog` directive, you can specify a scope property that controls the visibility of the modal using the `show` attribute. So just set that to true to hide or show your modal!

e.g. HTML:

```
<modal-dialog show="modalVisible"><!--content goes here --></modal-dialog>
```

In controller:

```
(function() {
    var myController = function($scope){
        $scope.modalVisible = true;

        $scope.newAdd = function(){
            if($scope.form.$valid){
                $scope.modalVisible = false;
            }else{

            }
        }
    };
    myController .$inject = ['$scope'];
    angular.module('app').controller('myController ',myController );
}());
```

Comment: I already tried that before does not work, neither it gives out any error in the console :( Any Idea?

Comment: [It works for me](http://plnkr.co/edit/YPpNLZDhQPufTs3RSTGH). Make sure you are setting your `modalVisible` property on the correct scope.

Comment: please see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YUdxLUrpYevus8TY6rWB?p=preview). This is what I am trying to achieve and does not work. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: In your plunkr, you just need to change `ng-click="hideModal()"` on your Add Address button to `ng-click="toggleModal()"` and it should be golden.